# How do you silence exptions in python, but still perform the action?

Tags: python, exception, tkinter

For some reason, closing a tkinter popup window with a button requires you to update the window to close it (otherwise it will just sit there), but calling update to close the window raises an exception.

I've tried the following, which works but raises an exception, which I cant have in the final product:

```
Button1 = ttk.Button(popupWindow, text="Close", command=popupWindow.destroy)
Button1.pack(expand = Y)
while popupWindow:
      time.sleep(0.1)
      popupWindow.update()
```

I've also tried the obvious try/except method:

```
Button1 = ttk.Button(popupWindow, text="Close", command=popupWindow.destroy)
Button1.pack(expand = Y)
while popupWindow:
      time.sleep(0.1)
      try:
           popupWindow.update()
      except:
           pass
```

This just causes the program to hang and become unresponsive, as if it's waiting for popupWindow.update() to be called. Is there a way to just silence the exception that's raised?

Comment: Can you please show us the exception. Instead of silencing the exception you should be finding the root cause and fix the code so that the exception doesn't occur in the first place. Also, using a `while` statement and `time.sleep` is not a recommended way to write a GUI. If you can give us a better [mcve], perhaps we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: It's not a GUI, it's a popup window inside a GUI that warns a user that the value is out of range. All it has is a close button. I will have to get the exact exception later, but it's something like "cant call popupWindow.update(), popupWindow no longer exists"

Comment: If you're waiting for a button click or for a widget to go away, tkinter has built-in features for doing that which don't require you to use a loop or to call `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a while loop, `sleep`, and `update` to wait for a button click or to wait for a window to go away. Those are the root cause of the exception you're seeing.

Tkinter has functions specifically for that purpose. By using one of these features you don't have to try to catch an exception since no exception will be thrown.

In your case, it appears you're wanting to wait for a widget to be destroyed. You can use tkinter's 'wait_window` function which does exactly that -- it waits for a window to be destroyed.

Here's a contrived example of a popup window. When you create it, it centers a new window on its parent, then waits until the window is destroyed. This example uses a `Frame` as the base, but you could also use `Toplevel` or `Canvas` or any other widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

class PopupWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, message):
        tk.Frame.__init__(
            self, parent,
            borderwidth=2, relief="raised",
            background="bisque",
        )
        label = tk.Label(self, text=message, bg=self.cget("background"))
        ok_button = tk.Button(self, text="Ok", command=self.destroy)

        ok_button.pack(side="bottom", pady=10)
        label.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)

        # center this widget on parent window
        self.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

        # wait until the window has been destroyed
        self.wait_window(self)
```

Here's an example of using this widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("400x400")

        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Do Something", command=self.do_something)
        button.pack(side="top")

        self.root.mainloop()

    def do_something(self):
        print("doing something...")
        print("waiting...")
        popupWindow = PopupWindow(self.root, "Click button to continue")
        print("done waiting...")

ex = Example()
```

Comment: That solved the problem. I thought something was odd about the way I was doing it. I would up vote...but I cant.

Comment: @Gacekky1 you should *always* be able to vote on answers to your own question.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."